# how is "cumulative map pmem" calculated?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My MR job has the following characteristics :

```
input size: 2 GB
chunk size: 128 MB
cluster size: 17 nodes
Distribution: MapR
```

I can see that "Cumulative Map PMem" size as 15 GB when I run my MR job.
And I have got to know that "Cumulative Map PMem" is Physical Memory counter representing total physical memory that has been used while executing MR job.

I would like to know how exactly this "Cumulative Map PMem" is calculated ? How is this shooting up to 15 GB.